# How to install Tesseract OCR on Databricks

Tags: tesseract, databricks, azure-databricks, python-tesseract

I am trying to run the following script on a databrick python notebook:

```
pip install presidio-image-redactor
pip install pytesseract
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg

from PIL import Image
from presidio_image_redactor import ImageRedactorEngine
import pytesseract

image = Image.open("images/ImageData.PNG")

engine = ImageRedactorEngine()

redacted_image = engine.redact(image, (255, 192, 203))
```

Upon running the last line, I'm getting the error below:

**TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH.**

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `%sh` in a separate cell to execute the shell commands on the driver node. To install tesseract, you can do:

```
%sh apt-get -f -y install tesseract-ocr
```

If you need to install it to all nodes of the cluster, you need to use [cluster init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) with the same command (without `%sh`)