# Is there a way to OCR images in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ocr, python-tesseract

I can not find an open source solution for OCRing images in PySpark. I know solutions like pytesseract exist, but not sure if they will play nicely with PySpark since the tesseract-ocr will need to be installed in the linux machines. Are there any open source OCR solutions that would play nicely with PySpark?

Comment: PySpark doesn't replace Linux and still is able to run "locally installed" modules of each executor

Comment: Start here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a pure python library. pytesseract calls a linux library called tesseract-ocr which I was able to install on a Spark cluster. You can also install this on your Spark cluster fairly easily and it works well.

Here's an answer on how to install it on Databricks. I used global init scripts to install it:

[How to install Tesseract OCR on Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807660/how-to-install-tesseract-ocr-on-databricks)